# How to anchor link in a accordion

Tags: html

it's possible to target #kodak in accordion with div id?

I just want to make link www.xy.cz/#15248756/#kodak , something like this, when user click on link, it will redirect to the accordion and to text with id "kodak".

Thank you.

See code below

```
<div class="vc_tta-panel vc_active" id="15248756">
 <div class="body">
  <div class="content" id="kodak">
   <p>text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple fragment identifiers on a single element, so the only way to do this would be to change the accordion implementation so it didn't depend on fragment ids in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Wikipedia how they are linking table of content to the respective sections.
In essence it is like:

```
<a href="#kodak">link to Kodak Cameras</a>
<h1 id="kodak">Kodak Cameras</h1>
```